# Subclass template in C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I know in java we can do this:

```
class A<T extends B>
{
...
}
```

Can we do the same with templates in C++?
For example i want to have a templated class A in witch the template T that we pass are subclasses of another class B like the java example above. Any ideas?

EDIT:
In one of the answers i was asked to show my code because i had link errors using the answers.
Here it is (from deep to the main):

```
//ComponentManager.h
...
template <typename T,  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
Component* AddComponent(rUUID uuid);
...

//ComponentManager.cpp
...
template <typename T,  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
Component* ComponentManager::AddComponent(rUUID uuid)
{
...
}

//Engine.h
...
template <typename T,  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void AddComponent(rUUID);
...

//Engine.cpp
...
template <typename T,  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void Engine::AddComponent(rUUID uuid)
{
...
}
...


//main.cpp
...
e.AddComponent<Position>(a->GetUUID());
...
```

Comment: You want to pass a generic child of B?

Comment: is_base_of<T,K>::type might do it

Comment: That's just has a little sense, since if T meets the requirements of A, it would work, and it would not compile otherwise.

Comment: @Unit978: Yes i want to pass a template subclass T of B in class A

Comment: @TheArtist: Why do you want to do that (rule out template arguments which aren't subclasses of B)?

Comment: "Subclass" is not well defined in context of C++.

Comment: Seriously, do you have a good reason for this requirement? There may be valid reasons, but it kind of goes against the whole idea of generic programming with templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class A
{
    // ...
};
```

[Here is a demo showing its use.](http://ideone.com/Qz8ydu#view_edit_box)

Comment: This is what i want but i cannot get it to work with member functions, i get link errors :/... Any ideas?

Comment: @TheArtist Can you show me the code you are using? I find it hard to understand how functions have anything to do with this. :)

Comment: I edited the post above please check it and tell me if you find a solution ;)

Comment: @TheArtist Your problem is that templates can only be defined in the translation unit in which it was declared. You'll get a linker error otherwise. However, you can include an explicit instantiation of your method in the cpp file in which you use it. For example: `template void Engine::AddComponent(rUUID);`. The other option is to simply merge the definition with its declaration.

Comment: The link error also is: 
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Engine::AddComponent<class Position,0>(class rUUID)" (??$AddComponent@VPosition@@$0A@@Engine@@QAEXVrUUID@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: But i have also templated code with definition and declaration in different files working(.h and .cpp as usual). Why isn't this working?

Comment: @TheArtist humm...I'm not sure. You might want to ask a question about that. I hope I held you with your initial question though.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to SFINAE you can go with `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
class A
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, "error message");
};
```